# Is it possible for a workflow to run the same job multiple times with different parameters?

Tags: amazon-web-services, pyspark, aws-glue

I am new to amazon's aws-glue and I am still trying to figure it out.

Currently, I have a python shell glue job and every time I execute it I change the job parameters.

I am looking at the workflows and have managed to parse the parameters through there and set a trigger to run every day.

**My question would be:**

Is there a way for workflows to create instances and concurrently execute the same job with different parameters?
Is creating multiple workflows is the only way to go about it?

Comment: one alternative could be to use lambda to generate the different configurations and trigger the glue jobs in parallel.

Comment: @thrasos were able to figure better solution ?

Answer (score 0):

I guess you did it through triggers right. Thats the way. You can parameterize your Glue Job (the underlying Python code) and create multiple triggers that uses the same Glue Job but different parameters. (You have an option to pass the job parameters in Triggers).

"Is there a way for workflows to create instances and concurrently execute the same job with different parameters? Is creating multiple workflows is the only way to go about it?"
-- I tried this approach but I didnot find any way out.